# Employment information on ESTA form

Tags: esta

I plan to visit the US for vacations. I'm completing the ESTA form but I'm not sure what to put under employment information. I'm a contractor for a US company (different city/state as destination and I'm not visiting them). Since I'm a contractor should I list it as self-employed or do I put the company information?

Thanks!

Comment: This guide https://esta-center.com/en/flow/index.html states: *Select “Yes” if you have been working, or have work experience in the past, and answer either employment status or employer name (workplace).* As a contractor the correct option would be self-employed, AFAIK

Comment: Note that when you get to immigration on arrival, if the officer asks, you don’t “work for” that US company — they are a customer.

Comment: Adding onto @jcaron make sure that if they ask if you'll work while in the US you are very clear with your answer. If you have meetings with your client company those most likely fall under business meetings and therefore allowed on visa-free trips. Visa-free visitors are allowed to do the same things as B1/2 visitors. See this link for allowed activities https://workpermit.com/immigration/usa/us-b-1-business-visitor-visa-and-b-2-visitor-pleasure-visa